# How to retrieve data-attr value of input?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I set a `data-id="2"` attribute on a HTML input tag. For example: `<input data-id="2" value="test"/>`. How do I retrieve this value in my action? I'm using dynamic text inputs where they can be sub inputs themselves.

Comment: There cannot be any other inputs other than value of the input element. You can use javascript to create new hidden elements to store them.

Answer (score 0):

The action can only access data which has been submitted to it (using POST or GET). If you want to be able to access the id, you'll need to grab that value using Javascript and send it with the other form data when the form is submitted.